# python: adding an xml sub-element to a substring of a parent element's text

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

Suppose I have an XML element containing text, and I want to add sub-elements to some of the words.  For example to convert:

```
<s>I don't want to have to entertain every Tom, Dick, and Harry who comes through here.</s>
```

to

```
<s>I don't want to have to entertain every <name nid="n1">Tom</name>, <name nid="n2">Dick</name>, and <name nid="n3">Harry</name> who comes through here.</s>
```

I have a list of all the strings that need to be wrapped, and I can easily find their locations within the text string, but I can't figure out how to add a tag at a specific position (other than just building up the whole thing by using string manipulation).  Surely there's a better way using ElementTree or BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you at least most of the way to where you want to go:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    old = """
    <s>I don't want to have to entertain every Tom, Dick, and Harry who comes through here.</s>
    """
    names = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]

    soup = bs(old,'lxml')
    orig_tag = soup.s
    old_st_lst = orig_tag.string.split(' ')
    new_st_lst = []
    for ns in old_st_lst:
        t_ns = ns.replace(',','')    
        if t_ns in names:
            place = names.index(t_ns)+1
            new_el = f'<name nid="n{place}">{ns}</name>'
            new_st_lst.append(new_el)        

        else:
            new_st_lst.append(ns)    
    final = ' '.join(new_st_lst)    

    for item in soup.select('s'):
        item.string = final

    print(soup.text)
```

Output:

```
I don't want to have to entertain every <name nid="n1">Tom,</name> <name nid="n2">Dick,</name> and <name nid="n3">Harry</name> who comes through here.
```